# How to store data from an array in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, repository, symfony-3.4

*I need to get all $posts for each $sub_val but the problem that every $posts in foreach is crushed, and i get only the last one.*$

the result of `print_r($postcats)` is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_id] => 6 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [post_id] => 7 ) )
```

and the result of `print_r($para)` is

```
Array ( [id] => 6 ) 
Array ( [id] => 7 )
```

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$repository = $em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Post');
$postcats = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->select('t.id as post_id')
                    ->innerJoin('t.categories', 'c')
                    ->where('c.id = :category_id')
                    ->setParameter('category_id', $getidCat)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();


foreach ($postcats as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_val) { 
        $entitymanager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $para=array('id'=>$sub_val);
        print_r($para);
        $posts=$entitymanager->getRepository('SiteBundle:Post')
                            ->findBy($para);
    } 
}
return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', array(
            'posts' => $posts,
            'login' =>$usersesssion,
            )
        );
```

Comment: if you want to append a value to an array you can use `$para[]` (empty square bracket)

Comment: where i can  use it?

Comment: where you are assigning `$para[]=array('id'=>$sub_val);` and move the  following `print_r ` out of the loop

Comment: the problem is that i got just the last post wich is id is 7 the post of id 6 is crushed

Comment: or maybe `$posts[]` you should use and not `$para[] `

Comment: it doesn't work but thank you :)

Comment: you have to check how the `render ` function works and if it accepts an array for `$posts`

Answer (score 0):

*I found the solution i just modify the code from my controler and the index.html.twig i did the loop for*

```
    {   $session=$request->getSession();

        $usersesssion=$session->get('login');
        $getidCat=$category->getId();
    if($getidCat!=null){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $repository = $em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Post');
        $postcats = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->select('t.id as post_id')
                            ->innerJoin('t.categories', 'c')
                            ->where('c.id = :category_id')
                            ->setParameter('category_id', $getidCat)
                            ->getQuery()
                            ->getResult(); 

        $posts= $em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Post')->findAll();
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'login' =>$usersesssion,
        'postcats' =>$postcats,
        ));
    }else{
        echo 'ko';
        $postcats=null;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $posts= $em->getRepository('SiteBundle:Post')->findAll();
        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'login' =>$usersesssion,
        'postcats' =>$postcats,
        ));
    }}
```